# Installing pandas on mac

Tags: python

Having difficulties installing panda. Used this command:

```
pip install pandas
```

This returned an error:

> Cannot uninstall 'numpy'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Thereafter, I tried installing using this:

```
pip install --ignore-installed pandas
```

This returned an error:

> Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/numpy-1.15.1.dist-info'
>   Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Anyone can offer some sort of insight here?

Comment: Did you try using the `--user` option like the error message said...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you don't have permissions to install to the system directory. You can always do `pip install pandas --user`, as the error message suggests, which will make the package "user level". This means that `pandas` will install to a place on the filesystem that you're guaranteed to have access to.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:
    pip install --user --ignore-installed pandas

Comment: If an answer worked for you, then accept it (like you already did). Posting it as a new answer is redundant